# Is it possible to make a login programmatically to twitter in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a login to twitter by myself programmatically. Is it possible to make a login programmatically to twitter by importing their jar files.

Comment: can you please sent me a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying like you **store Username and Password and then use them to log-in without any user interaction**.

Then, **That's Not Possible** , AFAIK.

That *was possible through the Library in past* using function which accept paramter as unm and pwd but *now they are deprycated* and dont work at all as Twitter change its policy for security reasons ofcaurse.

So everytime you need to get AuthToken you will have to make user Login.

Answer (score 0):

[Jtwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php) gives you easy access to the Twitter API as does [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)